# Generalized Linked List: Adding Child Link whenever an opening bracket occurs

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Here is my code for generating a GLL for the string input: a,(b,c),d where (b,c) will be linked as a child at the next link of a.

```
GLL* generateList(char poly[])
{
    GLL* newNode = NULL, *first = NULL, *ptr = NULL;

    while (poly[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (poly[i] == ')')
        {
            return first;
        }
        else
        {
            if (poly[i] != ',')
            {
                if (poly[i] != '(')
                {
                    newNode = createNode(poly[i], 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    ++i;
                    newNode = createNode('#', 1);
                    newNode->dlink = generateList(poly);
                }
            }
        }

        if (first != NULL)
        {
            ptr = first;
            while (ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            first = newNode;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return first;
}
```

And here is the structure I used for each node.

```
    typedef struct gll
    {
       int tag;
       struct gll* next;
       char data;
       struct gll* dlink;
    } GLL;
```

I am not finding a way to add that child link to the parent link whenever the bracket opens. The programs runs in a loop.

Note: I have declared i=0 as a global variable to hold the position of character.

Edit: Here is the createNode function

```
GLL* createNode(char value, int flag)
{
 GLL* newNode;

 newNode = (GLL *) malloc(sizeof(GLL)*1);

 newNode->data = value;
 newNode->dlink = NULL;

 newNode->tag = flag;
 newNode->next = NULL;

return newNode;
}
```

Comment: There is no `struct gll` defined anywhere in the code you provided. Please, show a [mcve].

Comment: `struct gll* next;` - you have not defined a struct by *this* name.

Comment: If you got a compiler error / diagnostics message you must paste it as text into the question as well.

Comment: I have added the struct gll and there is no compile error or diagnostics message.

Comment: Ok... you need a stack here, to store the *past parents*, whenever you see `(` you push / recurse, whenever `)` you pop / return.

Comment: `createNode()` is also missing.

Comment: It is stuck in an infinite loop when I recurse wherever the program sees '('

Comment: what is `flags` supposed to be?

Comment: + you cannot use `generateList()` recursively in its current form because when it returns you have no idea of how many characters it consumed.

Comment: How do I do it then? Also, if flag is true then it means that the data is not to be considered but there is a child list to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do it then?

You could do something like that:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct gll
{
    int tag;
    struct gll* next;
    char data;
    struct gll* dlink;
} GLL;

GLL* createNode(char value, int flag)
{
    GLL* newNode = calloc(1, sizeof(*newNode));

    if (!newNode)
        return NULL;

    newNode->tag = flag;
    newNode->data = value;
    return newNode;
}

void freeList(GLL *list)
{
    for (GLL *current_node = list, *temp; current_node; current_node = temp) {
        temp = current_node->next;
        freeList(current_node->dlink);
        free(current_node);
    }
}

GLL* generateList(char *poly, size_t *pos)
{
    size_t const length = strlen(poly);
    GLL *head = NULL;
    GLL *tail = NULL;

    for (; *pos < length; ++*pos) {
        if (poly[*pos] == '(') {
            ++*pos;  // don't have the next called generateList() read '(' again
            tail->dlink = generateList(poly, pos);
            if (!tail->dlink) {
                freeList(head);
                return NULL;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if (poly[*pos] == ')') {
            return head;
        }
        else if (isalpha((char unsigned)poly[*pos])) {
            if (!head) {
                head = tail = createNode(poly[*pos], 0);
            }
            else {
                tail->next = createNode(poly[*pos], 0);
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if (poly[*pos] == ',')
            continue;

        fputs("Format error :(\n\n", stderr);
        freeList(head);
        return NULL;
    }

    return head;
}

void printList(GLL *list)
{
    for (GLL *node = list; node; node = node->next) {
        printf("%c ", node->data);
        if (node->dlink) {
            putchar('(');
            printList(node->dlink);
            printf("\b) ");
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    GLL *list = generateList("a,(b,(c,d,e(f)),g,h),i,j,k", &pos);

    printList(list);
    putchar('\n');

    freeList(list);
}
```

#### Output

a (b (c d e (f)) g h) i j k

> Also, if flag is true then it means that the data is not to be considered but there is a child list to be linked.

Sorry, but I don't get how there could be a child list if there is no data for the node.